# 4th order PDE -- solved using Fourier Transforms?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, fourier-transform

Say I had a PDE:

$$u_t + u_{xxxx} + u = f(x)$$

with IC $u(t=0)=s(x)$.

How does one use Fourier transforms to solve this? If it were second order ($u_{xx}+u_{yy} = 0$), one could use a sine/cosine transform e.g.:

$$U(k,y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x,y)$$

would be the Fourier transform so that

$$-k^2~u(k,y)+\frac{\partial }{\partial y^2}u(k,y)=0$$

Where do I start to even solve a pde of this nature?

Comment: By doing what you always do and applying the FT to each term to get $$\hat{u}_{t}(k,t) + k^{4} \hat{u}(k,t) + \hat{u}(k,t) = \hat{f}(k)$$

Comment: how do I solve that?